# How can I make high charts in ASP.NET using a query?

Tags: asp.net, charts

This is my code for getting data from the database and showing it in a tabular form. This is working fine and now I want a chart/bar graph to show values for this, too. I don't know how to do this. Please help.

```
query = "select a,b from abc";            
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
GridDanish.DataSource = dt;
GridDanish.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the namespace **System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;** for creating my charts and save it as .jpg or whatever I want. Here is my code example how I use it:

```
   public static class ChartService
            {
                public static async Task CreateChart(Dictionary<DateTime, int> model)
                {
                    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Counter", typeof(int));

                    CultureInfo deDe = new CultureInfo("de-De");

                    foreach (var item in model)
                    {              
                        DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
                        r[0] = item.Key.ToString("MMMM yyyy", deDe);
                        r[1] = item.Value;
                        dt.Rows.Add(r);
                    }
                    dataSet.Tables.Add(dt);

                    //prepare chart control...
                    Chart chart = new Chart();
                    chart.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
                    chart.Width = 780;
                    chart.Height = 250;            
                    //create serie...
                    Series serie1 = new Series();
                    serie1.Name = "Serie1";
                    serie1.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 127, 102);
                    serie1.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 127, 102);
                    serie1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                    serie1.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
                    serie1.BorderWidth = 3;
                    serie1.ShadowColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 127, 102);
                    serie1.ShadowOffset = 0;            
                    //serie1.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                    serie1.XValueMember = "Name";
                    serie1.YValueMembers = "Counter";
                    serie1.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 8.0f);
                    serie1.BackSecondaryColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 127, 102);
                    serie1.LabelForeColor = Color.FromArgb(81, 80, 84);
                    chart.Series.Add(serie1);
                    //create chartareas...
                    ChartArea ca = new ChartArea();
                    ca.Name = "ChartArea1";
                    ca.BackColor = Color.White;
                    ca.BorderWidth = 1;
                    ca.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200);           
                    ca.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;           
                    ca.AxisX = new Axis();
                    ca.AxisY = new Axis();
                    ca.AxisX.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(171, 171, 171);
                    ca.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
                    ca.AxisY.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(171, 171, 171);  
                    ca.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(171, 171, 171);
                    ca.AxisY.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(82, 82, 82);
                    ca.AxisX.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(82, 82, 82);
                    chart.ChartAreas.Add(ca);
                    //databind...
                    chart.DataBind();
                    //save result...
                    chart.SaveImage("example\\temp\\img\\chart.jpg", ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
            }
```

The Output is something like this:

[image: chart]

Hope, this is, what you searching for. chears